# .NET: Async socket whose callback runs on the GUI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I used to code in Delphi, and I seem to remember there being an async-socket class where, after the async operation (e.g., a read) had been performed, a message was posted to the app's message loop, and the app picked up the "finished reading" notification simply by pumping the message loop.

The advantage of this was that the callback ran on the same thread as the one that made the 'read' call, which avoided threading nightmares (e.g., data races, having to marshal to the GUI thread before touching the controls, etc.).

Is it possible to do this in .NET?  I've searched all over and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

The network stack and UI stacks aren't tightly coupled, so no. However, in your async callback you can use

```
someControl.Invoke(workToDo, args);
```

to switch back (via the message loop) to the UI thread in winforms, or Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF.

Comment: Okay.  I wonder whether this is possible in pure Win32?  I ask because I had previously assumed that the Delphi component I used was simply a wrapper around Win32, and that Win32 itself was what posted the message to the Win32 message queue after the async operation had completed.